# Firefox no transition when fading back in an image

Tags: html, css, firefox

I made a nice transition effect when switching between images, it sets the opacity to 0 (With a transition of all .5s) then .5s later (Via setTimeout) the src of the image is changed and it should fade back in.

It works fine on Chrome and IE but on firefox the image fades out and then instead of fading back to opacity:1 it just jumps straight to it.

Here is my code

Javascript:

```
AddEventListener(window, 'load', function () {
    window.FadeinTime = 500;
    var LargeImageDiv = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
    window.LargeImage = LargeImageDiv.childNodes[1];
    var LargeImageCaption = LargeImageDiv.childNodes[3];
    var SlideText = ['Videography', 'Photography', 'Walkthroughs', 'Fine Art'];
    window.Images = []; //Some image links
    LargeImage.src = '/Resources/Home/' + window.Images[0];
    window.AutoSlide = setInterval(function () {
        var SlideNo = parseInt(LargeImage.getAttribute('data-slide')) + 1;
        var SlideTextNo = parseInt(LargeImage.getAttribute('data-slideText')) + 1;
        if (SlideNo == Images.length) SlideNo = 0;
        if (SlideTextNo == SlideText.length) SlideTextNo = 0;
        LargeImage.setAttribute('data-slide', SlideNo.toString());
        LargeImage.setAttribute('data-slideText', SlideTextNo.toString());
        LargeImageDiv.setAttribute('style', '-khtml-opacity:0;-moz-opacity:0;-ms-filter: alpha(opacity=0);-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0;');
        setTimeout(function () {
            LargeImage.src = '/Resources/Home/' + Images[SlideNo];
            LargeImageCaption.innerHTML = SlideText[SlideTextNo];
            LargeImageDiv.removeAttribute('style');
        }, window.FadeinTime)
    }, 2500)
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="LargeImage" class='NoSelect' onclick='if(event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") return; var u = this.childNodes[3].innerHTML; window.location=(u=="Videography"||u=="Walkthroughs"?"/Videos/View/"+u:"/Pictures/View/"+u);'>
    <img src="" data-slide='0' data-slideText='0'/>
    <pre class='Caption'>Videography</pre>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body > div#Content > div#LargeImage  {
    cursor:pointer;
    max-height:490px;
    min-height:300px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
        -webkit-transition:.5s;
        -o-transition:.5s;
        transition:.5s;
}

body > div#Content > div#LargeImage > button  {
     position:absolute;
     bottom:5px;
     right:5px;
     ;
}

 body > div#Content > div#LargeImage > img  {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-10%;
}

body > div#Content > div#LargeImage > pre  {
    height:50px;
    font-size:80px;
}
```

Comment: post the code. Are you positive the image is done loading?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Added the code now. The crazy thing is, the first time you load the page when it has to download the files it works fine but when it's reading from the cache it doesn't fade the new image src back in.